# glTexSubImage2D does not work correctly

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I've written a very simple OpenGL application. Its goal is to load a texture and draw it on a plane. If I use the function 'glTexSubImage2D' the plane is not textured and the function 'glGetError' returns the error '1281' (invalid value). However if I use the function 'glTexImage2D' my plane plane is textured correctly (and I have no error).

Here's a piece of my code :

```
void core::RootDevice::LoadTexture(char const *pFileName)
{
    SDL_Surface *pSurface = IMG_Load(pFileName);
    char *pPixels = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pSurface->pixels);
    uint32_t bytePerPixel = pSurface->format->BitsPerPixel;

    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    {
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboID);
        {
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

            //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pSurface->w,       //NO ERROR : All is ok
                //pSurface->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pPixels);

            glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, pSurface->w,        //ERROR : 1281
                pSurface->h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pPixels);

            std::cout << glGetError() << std::endl;
            getchar();
        }
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And the rendering code :

```
void core::RootDevice::Render(void)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And the result is the followings:

[image]

Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glTexSubImage2D()` is used to replace parts or all of a texture that already has image data allocated. You have to call `glTexImage2D()` on the texture at least once before you can use `glTexSubImage2D()` on it. Unlike `glTexSubImage2D()`, `glTexImage2D()` allocates image data. You can use `NULL` for the last (`data`) argument to `glTexImage2D()` if you only want to allocate image data, and later set the data with `glTexSubImage2D()`.

Newer versions of OpenGL (4.4 and ES 3.0) have a new entry point `glTexStorage2D()` that can be used as an alternative to `glTexImage2D()` to allocate the image data for a texture without specifying the data. It is similar to calling `glTexImage2D()` with `data = NULL`, but also allows specifying ahead of time if space for mipmaps will be needed.